# Howto set correct Index for SQL join with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, indexing, where-clause

i have searched google for a while but i don't find a answer that solves my "Problem".

I have 3 Exampletables with the follwing structure.

Customer:

- CustomerId
- FirstName
- LastName
- Gender
- IsDeleted

Invoice:

- InvoiceId
- CustomerId
- Amount
- Positions
- IsValid

InvoicePos:

- InvoicePosId
- InvoiceId
- PosName
- IsPaid

Now i'd like to join them with the following Query.

```
SELECT T1.FirstName,
       T1.LastName,
       T2.Amount,
       T3.PosName
FROM Customer AS T1
     JOIN Invoice AS T2 ON T1.CustomerId = T2.CustomerId
     JOIN InvoicePos AS T3 ON T2.InvoiceId = T3.InvoiceId
WHERE T1.FirstName = 'A'
  AND T1.LastName = 'B'
  AND T2.Positions = 3
  AND T3.IsPaid = 1;
```

For table `Customer` i have a Index for FirstName, LastName, CustomerId

For `InvoicePos` i have a Index for IsPaid, InvoiceId, InvoicePosId

But what Index should i use for Table `Invoice`?

Comment: Indexes aren't something that can simply be "taught" in a simple answer; there's a far greater understanding required, You would likely be better reading articles, and documentations, or even going on a course, on best ways to index your tables. You've made no mention of Primary keys, and if they're clustered, which makes a big different as well.

Comment: t1, t2 and t3 are poor table aliases. Use table aliases that make sense, like C for Customer.

Comment: To expand on @jarlh's comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT T1.FirstName, T1.LastName, T2.Amount, T3.PosName
FROM Customer T1 JOIN
     Invoice T2
     ON T1.CustomerId = T2.CustomerId JOIN
     InvoicePos T3
     ON T2.InvoiceId = T3.InvoiceId
WHERE T1.FirstName = 'A' AND
      T1.LastName = 'B' AND
      T2.Positions = 3 AND
      T3.IsPaid = 1;
```

I would recommend the following indexes:

- `Customer(FirstName, LastName, CustomerId)`
- `Invoice(CustomerId, InvoiceId, Positions, Amount)`
- `InvoicePost(InvoiceId, IsPaid, PosName)`.

First, these are covering indexes for your query.  So, only the indexes are needed.  If you have additional columns in the `SELECT`, you can remove the `SELECT`-only columns from the indexes.

The idea is to start with the most selective `WHERE` conditions.  I am guessing that the name restrictions are the most restrictive.  Hence, the indexing starts on `Customer` and uses the `WHERE` conditions.  Then, additional columns from `ON` and `SELECT` clauses are added.

For the remaining tables, the `JOIN` columns are the first keys in the index, followed by `WHERE` and `SELECT` columns.

Comment: Thanks this helps me to understand the problem better. The Only question remaining is for table 2 how to set the index. "CustomerId + Positions" or "InvoiceId + Positions"

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the query optimizer on your query and SQL will give you the best indexes to apply and also show you the % performance increase.

Comment: That won't help if it's a non-clustered index; it won't be a covering index. And even then, a clustered index on those 2 columns alone won't aid the `WHERE`, which makes no reference to those columns.

Answer (score 0):

For only this exact query putting some index on Table2/`Invoice` with `CustomerId, Positions` would be ideal.

Although generally the following indices would make sense:

```
Customer:
  unique index on CustomerId
  index on LastName, FirstName
Invoice:
  unique index on InvoiceId
  index on CustomerId
InvoicePos:
  unique index on InvoicePosId
  unique index on InvoiceId, InvoiceId
  index on IsPaid, InvoiceId  (for your scenario)
```

Answer (score 0):

use these indexes :

```
Create Index IX__Customer_001 on Customer (CustomerId,FirstName,LastName)
Create Index IX__Invoice_001 on Invoice (CustomerId,InvoiceId,Positions) include (Amount)
Create Index IX__InvoicePos_001 on InvoicePos (InvoiceId,IsPaid) include (PosName)
```

you must use the fields that used only as select columns on include Clause , and put predicates on the key columns

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! it'll help if you take the time to explain your answer, so the OP understands why you've made these choices. Code only answer often don't help other users learn, especially if they don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

My Mainproblem is to understand in which order the Query is resolved.

There are some Indexs on the AI-Columns (CostumerId, InvoiceId, InvoicePosId).

The Index on Table 1 (Firstname, Lastname, CostumerId) makes sense because it filters the names an then joins with the Invoicetable.

But the second Index is which is not clear for me.